# Array does not connect with the tableView(numberOfRowsInSection) method

Tags: swift, http, alamofire

I have an array which I will store all data that I get from http request and display them on tableView but it seems that `tableView(numberOfRowsInSection)` does not recognize the change in the array because the count remains as 0.

```
class OrdersViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var arr = [[String: AnyObject]]()
    var selectedIndex = -1
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let baseUrl = "my url"
        let consumer_key = "consumer_key"
        let consumer_secret = "consumer_key"
        let url = "\(baseUrl)?consumer_key=\(consumer_key)&consumer_secret=\(consumer_secret)&status=processing"
        
        let headers2 = ["Accept": "application/json"]
        Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers2)
            .responseJSON { response in
                    self.arr.append(data from request)
                }
        }
        
        let url2 = "\(baseUrl)?consumer_key=\(consumer_key)&consumer_secret=\(consumer_secret)&status=pending"
        Alamofire.request(url2, headers: headers2)
            .responseJSON { response in
                    self.arr.append(data from request)
                    print("arr", self.arr)
                }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        print("after request", self.arr)
        return self.arr.count
    }
}
// and some other code...
```

I do get data from the http request successfully and it gets updated in my Alamofire call but "after request" keeps printing empty array. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `tableView.reloadData()` *after* changing your `self.arr` property. The corresponding [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata) provides further details:

> Call this method to reload *all* the data that is used to construct the table, including cells, section headers and footers, index arrays, and so on. For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are visible.

If you plan on changing your `self.arr` property in many places, you could alternatively add a *property observer* to it:

```
var arr = [[String: AnyObject]]() {
    didSet { tableView?.reloadData() } 
}
```

...so you wouldn't need to copy-and-paste the same code all around ;-)

Comment: I put self.tableView.reloadData() after append method, but it still does not update my array in numberOfRowsInSection function. Besides, now it gives me an error saying `Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]` and `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x7fc0e80fe600; frame = (0 20; 375 598);.....`. Thank you for the help tho. Maybe my problem is something else.

Comment: @ckim16 You are welcome! Looks like you might have another issue, but not calling `reloadData()` was definitely a bug as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to move your request and response logic in one function and then call that function from `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad` and just after the call reload your tableview using `reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

use this code inside the Viewdidload

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

instead of

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: This still prints an empty array for my numberOfRowInSection function.

Comment: Check your console your Array values are displayed as string. Until your values are displayed in string your array is empty. Need to convert the string to array. then your array value is does not show the empty. Any problem will be there can you show me the console output?